# Dynamic DOM Element not picked up as lastChild

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

i have a strange issue exhibiting itself in firefox (havent tested ie etc but need it to work in firefox none the less). I am using ajax to populate a parent div with divs containing information returned from a DB. The server side is PHP with a while loop that iterates over a result set and echos each div.

The whole script works fine and populates the parent div (#ID of parent div =' webses') with a varying number of child nodes, the problem i have is that when i check the last child node after getting a new set of divs via ajax the lastChild is reported as the previously populated lastChild.

An example is:

'#webses' has 4 childNodes (divs), the last childNode has ID 'no4', i then repopulate the entire set of childNodes under #webses adding a new div with ID 'no5', i then query the ID of the last child 'immidiately' at the end of the function that repopulates the div and the lastChild is returned as 'no4'. I can then run the same query (once the function is complete) to check lastChild on #webses (via browser address bar) and then no5 is returned correctly!

Here is an example of code that exhibits the issue (using alert to show value of ID on lastChild):

```
function populateWebses() {

//populates parentNode DIV 'webses' with divs populated via AJAX
populateParentNodeViaAJAX();

alert(document.getElementById("webses").lastChild.id);
}
```

the query to see the lastChild is executed immidiately after DOM  under '#webses' is updated with new childNodes, i guess this is the issue, but why?

Any help much appreciated.

Dan

Comment: could you add the code for populateParentNodeViaAJAX()? Is it a synchronous call? asynchronous?

Answer (score 2):

AJAX means asynchronous Javascript. The populateParentNodeViaAJAX() method has not completed yet when the alert is executed, so it is returning the "old" value.

If you need to perform some sort of operation that depends on the fact that an Ajax method has completed, you need to use a callback mechanism (that calls function X only after the Ajax call is done).

Comment: It's not requesting more than a few bytes of info but i guess the asynchronous request still takes a little too long to update the DOM :( as you suggest ill be using a callback function, thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: Yep, that is likely the case.

Comment: It's not just the DOM update time. It's the time required for a round trip to the server as well